# cannot import name WebApplicationClient

Tags: python, twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth, twython

I am trying to run [this program](https://github.com/ebottabi/queshuns) but I am receiving this error:

```
python questions_app.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "questions_app.py", line 8, in <module>
    from filter_daemon import *
  File "/home/mona/danac/queshuns/filter_daemon.py", line 5, in <module>
    from twython import TwythonStreamer
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twython/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from .api import Twython
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twython/api.py", line 14, in <module>
    from requests_oauthlib import OAuth1, OAuth2
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests_oauthlib/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .oauth2_auth import OAuth2
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests_oauthlib/oauth2_auth.py", line 2, in <module>
    from oauthlib.oauth2 import WebApplicationClient, InsecureTransportError
ImportError: cannot import name WebApplicationClient
```

What are some possible options to solve it?
I am using Ubuntu 13.04 and Python 2.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you do not have oauthlib.

```
pip install oauthlib
```

Comment: I installed it but I have yet the same error: `pip install oauthlib
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): oauthlib in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Cleaning up...`

Comment: Try pip install -I oauthlib . If that doesnt work try reinstalling twython : pip install -I twython